# New window displays upon screen capturing using Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, automation, krypton

Is there a way, not to prompt a new window for your screenshot code when it is in a class ?

This is where I call the class within  my code:

```
findText(By.xpath("//*[text()='Table']")).click
pause(3)
findLink(By.cssSelector("button.btn.btn-link[aria-label='Maximize']")).click

new takesScreenshot();

findLink(By.cssSelector("button.btn.btn-link[aria-label='Dashlet Actions']")).click
```

This is my class code for screenshot:

```
public class takesScreenshot   {


 {
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    File tempFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    try {
        FileUtils.copyFile(tempFile,new File( "C:\\Screenshots\\"+ "SS1" + ".png"));
       } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO handle exception
    }
```

Right now when the class is called it prompts a new window that's why i cannot do screenshot for what i supposed to capture please help thanks!

Answer (score 3):

its because you are starting a new chrome driver instance in your takeScreenshot method. Take out the line:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

if you need your driver instance, you may need to pass it into the takeScreenshot method